# to build a dynamic query through java code

Tags: java

I have one entity class which has certain tables attributes in it . The object of this class will be populated in a helper class with values for the attributes . Now i want a method that would dynamically build an SQL query statement( a separate private method), query the table ( a separate private method) for all matching rows, map the output results (a separate private method) to a list of AuditBO objects

Comment: What is your question? Please show us what you have done so far and what specific prolems you are running in.

Comment: Maybe some kind of ORM might help here like the use of Hibernate.
It lets you query on your model.

Comment: Or if you want better readable statements and less String acrobatics you could look into QueryDSL. http://www.querydsl.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful.

When the `Table` class is initialized, all the input values will be initialized. When `getSelectQuery` method is called, based on inputs select query will be formed. And `populatePreparedSt` will be called to set PreparedStatement. Finally based on the inputs, you set in constructor of `Table`, you will get the query and result.

Table class:

```
public class TableRow {
    private String attibute1;
    private String attibute2;
    private int id;
    // getter and setters

    public final String selectQuery = " SELECT ID, ATTIBUTE1, ATTIBUTE2 FROM TABLEROW ";

    public CECardLogRow(int id, String attibute1, String attibute2) {
        this.id = id;
        this.attibute1 = attibute1;
        this.attibute2 = attibute2;
    }

    public String getSelectQuery () {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        boolean whereClauseAdded = false;       
        sql = sql.append(selectQuery);
        if (id > -1) {
            sql.append(" WHERE ID = ? ");
            whereClauseCt++;
        }
        if (attibute1 != null && attibute1.trim() != "") {
            sql.append(whereClauseAdded ? " AND " : " WHERE ");
            sql.append(" ATTIBUTE1 = ? ");
        }
        if (attibute2 != null && attibute2.trim() != "") {
            sql.append(whereClauseAdded ? " AND " : " WHERE ");
            sql.append(" ATTIBUTE2 = ? ");
        }
        return sql.toString();
    }

    public void populatePreparedSt (PreparedStatement ps) {
        int i = 1;
        if (id > -1) {
            ps.setInt(i++, id);         
        }
        if (attibute1 != null && attibute1.trim() != "") {
            ps.setString(i++, attibute1);
        }
        if (attibute2 != null && attibute2.trim() != "") {
            ps.setString(i++, attibute2);
        }           
    }
}
```

Calling method:

```
public List<TableRow> getData (int id, String attibute1, String attibute2) {
    List<TableRow> rows = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(id, attibute1, attibute2);          
        String sql = row.getSelectQuery();
        con = global.getConnection(); // get connection
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        row.populatePreparedSt(ps);
        rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
        while (rs.next()) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            // get data
            row.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));// and so on             
            rows.add(tableRow);
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqe) {
        throw sqe;
    } finally() {
        // closeConnection
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: I think people you have got me wrong. I have made an entity class as EntityBo . This class will have all the fields of the tables . Now i'll have one more helper class which will populate the fields in the EntityBo class . Now i have populated this entity class also . After this in the helper class we need a method which will dynamically build the sql query . So basically i am stuck over here to make a method which will build  a query dynamically based on the input attributes populated .

Comment: The query will be some what like this :- SELECT * from CCMS.USER_ACT_AUDIT where CLIENT_ID = ‘GUI’ AND USER_ID = ‘pagi@yahoo.co.in’ AND ACTION = ‘searchParties’ with ur . The attributes mentioned in the query here will be populated in the entity class and based on these attributes the query will be made dynamically . So i just need a method to build the query dynamically .

Comment: Don't you see the query is getting builded dynamically based on inputs?

Comment: Can some one explain the utility of populatePreparedSt() method

Comment: Updated answer with explanation.